# Django form undefined error?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I defined my forms.py with this but having a 'ModelForm has no model class specified.' error. Why?

```
from django import forms


class SearchForm(forms.ModelForm):
    search_query = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the model that is associated with your form, since you are using a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms).

Structurally, it would look like:

```
class SearchForm(forms.ModelForm):
    search_query = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        model = ModelHere
```